# 2d transform affect parent only

Tags: css, 2d, transform

I'm using transform:matrix on some parent element, but i want that child element is not affected by it.

I've got something like that for parent:

```
transform:matrix(0.98,-0.53,0.82,0.57,0,0);
-ms-transform:matrix(0.98,-0.53,0.82,0.57,0,0);
-webkit-transform:matrix(0.98,-0.53,0.82,0.57,0,0);
```

and inside that element is child.
I've tried position:absolute, or fixed for the child, but that doesn't work. I can always reset matrix positions for the child by changing parameters back to normal, but it is not easy to get that exact 100% accurate.

Adding jsfiddle for full code: https://jsfiddle.net/ypvoa8Ly/

Comment: the only solution is to apply the inverse transformation. Or change your HTML in order to separate element ... share your full code btw

Comment: hi again :) i can't seperate elements cause the idea is too use the transformed element as the clip-path alternative, cause i can't make it working in IE... so i'm transforming parent with the overflow hidden ;)

Comment: so share your full code :) maybe we will find a trick [and am also thinking about the clip path issue ;) ]

Comment: here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ypvoa8Ly/

right now i wanna make the image just straight forward... not sure what to change in transform matrix to make it right

Comment: you can instead of matrix use simply transformation that you can easily inverse like this :https://jsfiddle.net/ypvoa8Ly/2/

Comment: thnx a lot! works like a charm... simple solutions are always the best... you can make it as an answer so i can check it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using matrix transformation that can be hard to invert on child element. You can instead use simple transformation in the same property that you can easily invert.

You may also adjust the position of the inner element to avoid some *bad* overflow:

```css
.img-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin:10px auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(45deg) skew(-20deg);
  position:relative;
}

.img-wrapper img {
  transform: skew(20deg) rotate(-45deg);
  position:absolute;
  top:-15%;
  bottom:-15%;
  left:-15%;
  right:-15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img class="main-img" src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5nre6cxkQ1qbs7p5o1_r1_500.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Here is also another way to achieve something like this using gradient (since you cannot use clip-path):

```css
.image {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  background: 
  linear-gradient(40deg, #fff 28%, transparent 20%, transparent 75%, #fff 70%), 
  linear-gradient(-40deg, #fff 28%, transparent 20%, transparent 75%, #fff 20%), 
  url('http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m5nre6cxkQ1qbs7p5o1_r1_500.jpg') center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="image" ></div>
```